# Does this constant remind you of something?

Tags: number-theory, numerical-methods, recreational-mathematics

In my tries for solving a problem I repeatedly came across a couple of constants. This is an exciting news (well, just for me!) but there are not elegant. I cannot figure out what do they represent. That would be excellent if you know an equivalent representation for them. 
Here I write the most interesting one of them: **0.496077421**

Do you know this number?

**Info:**
I am doing some numerical experiments on the relations between various independent variables and one dependent variable (a polynomial regression). So there is no integral or a structural equation that the constant can be analytically estimate from. 
The data is also simulated, but the contact is there for various samples and runs. 
The data generation process has been tested very carefully, so the source of the constant is not from within the DGP.

Comment: Some context would be helpful.

Comment: $\displaystyle \int_0^1 0.496077421\,{\rm d}x.$

Comment: You can always try WolframAlpha for these kind of things, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.496077421. The possible closed forms don't seem to correspond to anything 'reasonable', but you might try more digits.

Comment: Maybe... give us the integrals and the community will figure it out? They're pretty good... to understate their brilliance...

Comment: Too few digits, could be anything really. Or nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest value found by an Inverse Symbolic Calculator is $$\sin \left(\frac{153 \pi }{926}\right)=\cos \left(\frac{155\pi  }{463}\right)\approx 0.496077404557205$$ I suppose that it is of absolutely no interest!

**Edit**

$$\sin \left(\frac{651209}{3941304} \pi \right)\approx 0.496077421000186$$ $$\tan \left(\frac{460169 }{3139303}\pi \right)\approx 0.496077421000020$$ $$\sinh \left(\frac{2029191}{4247830}\right)\approx 0.496077421000064$$

Comment: Wow! I was not familiar with Inverse Symbolic Calculator. This is amazing. However, it is not clear if I can explain theses expressions. I am working on it, and maybe I can post some new explanations.